# WPF Visual Studio: Главное окно не масштабируется под масштаб экрана Windows

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

После переустановки Visual Studio главное окно в любых WPF проектах перестало масштабироваться под выбранный в Windows масштаб. У меня установлен масштаб экрана на 125% и раньше окно и весь текст в нем увеличивались в размерах. Сейчас же, именно главное окно остается такого же размера, как и при 100% масштаба. Как это исправить?

Единственное, что я сделал кроме переустановки, это установил значение по инструкции отсюда: [ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/visualstudio/general/cannot-find-resource-named-error)

```
setx VSXAML_DISABLE_ON_DEMAND_RESOURCE_VALUES 1
```

---

Вот пример:

**Масштаб интерфейса 125%**
Главное окно и диалоговое

**размер обоих окон - `Height="450" Width="800"`**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А так при масштабе **150%**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**И я напоминаю, что размер у окон ОДИНАКОВЫЙ.**

Что с этим можно сделать?

---

**Код от главного:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpfApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpfApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        Background="DarkGray">
    <Grid Background="#222222">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="btn" Grid.Row="1" Content="Button"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Диалоговое:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpfApp.Dialog"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpfApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Dialog" Height="450" Width="800" Opacity="0.5">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Test Text" FontSize="25"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для меня так и остается непонятным, почему во всех WPF проектах (включая создание новых) сбилось масштабирование главного окна. Я не могу считать проблему решенной, так как окно должно масштабироваться самостоятельно, как происходило до этого, ведь я ничего не менял и не делал.

Так или иначе я нашел локальное решение проблемы для конкретного текущего проекта.

*Идея решения найдена [**здесь**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46428510/enhanced-system-dpi-scaling-with-vs2017) (спустя 2 дня поисков).*

---

Итак, все, что нужно сделать, это создать новый файл манифеста приложения и добавить туда параметр [**`gdiScaling`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests?redirectedfrom=MSDN#gdiScaling).

Для этого нажимаем ПКМ на проекте в обозревателе решений > Добавить > Создать элемент > Файл манифеста приложения.

Как указано в примере, я назвал его `GdiScaling.manifest` и добавил туда необходимое мне [**содержимое**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests?redirectedfrom=MSDN#dpiawareness):

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
 ...
  <asmv3:application>
    <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">
      <dpiAwareness>PerMonitorV2, unaware</dpiAwareness>
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
  </asmv3:application>
 ...
</assembly>
```

После этого все заработало как надо.

---

Однако повторюсь, что для меня это является всего лишь обходом проблемы, которая возникла из ничего после переустановки `Visual Studio`.

*Позже дополню ответ, если что-то ответят в поддержке среды разработки*