# WPF: Главное окно появляется не по центру, хотя соответствующий параметр установлен

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

В моем WPF приложении есть главное окно, для которого установлен параметр `WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"`, чтобы оно всегда появлялось по центру экрана.

Это работает, когда у меня установлен масштаб экрана Windows на **100%**

И окно появляется по центру:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако у меня маленький экран, поэтому я установил масштаб интерфейса на **125%**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Теперь окно появляется где-то сбоку**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Также я заметил, что само окно не меняется в размерах, в зависимости от выбранного масштаба. Причем, эта проблема касается только главного окна - диалоговые окна подстраивают свой размер под масштаб экрана и всегда появляются по центру.**

Это как-то связано с проблемой, которую я показал в [**прошлом вопросе**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1337036/wpf-visual-studio-%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0-windows).

Почему окно отображается не по центру и не меняет свой размер?

---

**Код:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpfApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Background="DarkGray">
    <Grid Background="#222222">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="btn" Grid.Row="1" Content="Button"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: а если изменить масштаб и перезайти в учетную запись, проблема сохраняется?

Comment: @aepot перезашел в учетную запись windows, предварительно изменив масштаб - ничего не меняется, окно остается тех же размеров, что и раньше

Comment: Так у вас размер окна явно задан 800x450 в пикселях, с чего вдруг размеру окна меняться? Изменения масштабирования меняет размер шрифта, а не окон. Размер шрифта наверняка тоже в пикселях задан, так? И я в предыдущем комменте имел в виду только проблему положения окна, но вы кажется уже про другое.

Comment: @aepot до этого-то все менялось, из-за кого-то бага сломалось. Просто, в [предыдущем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1337036/wpf-visual-studio-%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0-windows) у диалогового окна тоже явно задан размер, но оно подстраивается. Это какой-то баг?

Comment: В студии есть настройка, следовать параметрам системы масштабирования, или не следовать, из-за этого отладчик может перекрывать параметры системы. Я сам с этим не работал, но сталкивался с предупреждением студии об этом. Пробуйте запустить экзешник отдельно без отладчика, чтобы проверить. Должны быть где-то настройки студии на эту тему.

Comment: @aepot запускл отдельно, из папки bin\..\debug. Все тоже самое :(
Я тоже думаю, что это где-то в настройках сбилось, причем именно при компиляции, но вот где..

Comment: Вообще винда глючная штука в плане масштабирования. Эта проблема еще начиная с Windows XP присутствует. Как минимум, надо перезаходить в учетку после изменения масштаба. А вот где какие настройки студии по этой теме - я к сожалению не знаю.

Comment: @aepot посмотрите, пожалуйста, [что удалось решить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1337036/wpf-visual-studio-%d0%93%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%88%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%88%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0-windows/1337361#1337361) Насколько это правильное решение проблемы? Нормально ли будет оставить так или нужно добиться нормальной работы, чтобы окно масштабировалось само?

Comment: Нормальное решение, а вто только есть ли лучше - я не знаю. В принципе не сталкивался с этой проблемой.